# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Recipe[]>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch data from `firebase`, but facing an error

> "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'"

any idea? whats missing here?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import {RecipeService} from '../recipes/recipe.service';
import {Recipe} from '../recipes/recipe.model';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStorageService {

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
          private recipeService: RecipeService) {}

 storeRecipes() {
    return this.httpClient.put('https://ng-recipe-10b53.firebaseio.com/recipes.json',
      this.recipeService.getRecipes());
 }

  getRecipes() {
this.httpClient.get('https://ng-recipe-book.firebaseio.com/recipes.json');
  map(
    (response: Response) => {
      const recipes: Recipe[] = response.json();
      for (const recipe of recipes) {
        if (!recipe['ingredients']) {
          recipe['ingredients'] = [];
        }
      }
      return recipes;
    }
  )
  .subscribe(
    (recipes: Recipe[]) => {
      this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
    }
  );
 }

 }
```

Comment: There should be no ";" at the end of your get request. Map should be chained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `subscribe` on your HTTP call in the `getRecipes` method. The return value of `subscribe` is of type `Subscription`, not `Observable`. Thus, you cannot use that value in your `storeRecipes` method, because a `Subscription` cannot be observed; only an `Observable` can.

Moreover, your `getRecipes` logic is bad. You use `map` after your HTTP call in `getRecipes`, however there is a semicolon before it. Did you even execute this code? It is not valid TypeScript/Angular/RxJS and will not compile.

You can either chain your operators properly (using the old RxJS syntax), or use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) as in my example below (the new RxJS syntax).

Change your `getRecipes` function to this and it should work:

```
getRecipes() {
    this.httpClient
        .get('https://ng-recipe-book.firebaseio.com/recipes.json')
        .pipe(
            map((response: Response) => {
                const recipes: Recipe[] = response.json();
                for (const recipe of recipes) {
                    if (!recipe['ingredients']) {
                        recipe['ingredients'] = [];
                    }
                }
                return recipes;
            }),
            tap((recipes: Recipe[]) => {
                this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
            })
        );
}
```

And make sure to import `map` and `tap` from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer you think has solved your problem best.

Answer (score 29):

One thing that got me, there is a static and a pipeable version of many functions.

For example, `combineLatest(a$, b$).subscribe()` will give you a similar error about `OperatorFunction<T,R>` (T and R will vary based on your observables) *if you import it from rxjs/operators!*  Import it from rxjs and no problemo.

If you're playing around with something, your IDE might very well auto-import from rxjs/operators, and not change it when you try and use it outside a pipe.

Comment: this fixed my problem. But what is wrong if we import from rxjs/operators?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it per-se; it's usually the preferred way to do it.  The problem is that there are two different functions (e.g. `combineLatest`) being exported. The function from rxjs/operators returns `OperatorFunction<T,R>` (hence the error,) while the function from rxjs returns `Observable<R>`.  It does look like they're on the path of deprecating the non-preferred ways.  `combineLatest` from operators has `/** @deprecated Deprecated in favor of static combineLatest. */` for example.

Comment: That is just bad design... Having two functions with the same name -.-

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) with RxJS. These are functions that you pass to the `.pipe` method of Observables to operate on elements emitted by the Observable. You can also call `.subscribe` on Observables. Operators do not have a `.subscribe` method.

```
this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
  map(...)
).subscribe(...);
```

You pass `map`, the operator, into `.pipe`. You also call `.subscribe` on the observable itself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by adding a bracket )  at the end, cause I forgot it  XD

```
of(1,2,3).pipe(scan((acc, curr)=> acc + curr, 0).subscribe(console.log)
```

Gives this error.

```
of(1,2,3).pipe(scan((acc, curr)=> acc + curr, 0) ).subscribe(console.log)
```

No longer gives this error.