# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Product[], ParamMap>'

Tags: angular

```
constructor(productService: ProductService, categoryService: CategoryService, route:ActivatedRoute) {
    productService.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(switchMap((products:Product[])=> {
      this.product = products;
      return route.queryParamMap;

    })
    .subscribe(params=>{
      this.category =  params.get('category');

      this.filteredProduct = (this.category) ?
      this.product.filter(p=>p.category === this.category) :
      this.product;

    }));
```

error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'.

26     .subscribe(params=>{
        ~~~~~~~~~

Comment: `forkJoin(productService.getAll().snapshotChanges(), route.queryParamMap).subscribe([product, params]) => {/*yourcode*/})`

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<unknown>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.

Comment: Probably [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398107/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-operatorfunctionresponse-recipe)

Comment: You didn't close the brackets correctly. Above subscribe you should close like this: `}))` and at the end you should close like this: `})`.